# why Python range function in for loop running twice

Tags: python, loops, range

situation:
2 loops, expect the outer loop run once, then inter loop runs completely, then outer loop runs its 2nd... 
question: why the outer loop run twice before the inter loop get a chance to run?

Code:

```
def sort(a_list):
    for i in range(1,len(a_list)):
        print("i=",i)
        for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
            print("j=",j)
```

Test:
L=[9,6,1,3]

sort(L)

Result:

```
i= 1
i= 2   # here, the outer lopp ran twice then inter loop began.
j= 1
i= 3
j= 2
j= 1
```

Comment: Because the inner loop doesn't have any number to iterate over, when i = 1.

Comment: try doing the following for i =0 `[j for j in range(i-1,0,-1)]` you'll see that this value is empty

Comment: The inner loop **did** run. It performed zero iterations.

Answer (score 3):

It's because when `i = 1` the inner loop becomes `range(0,0,-1)` which is empty. So you don't print anything and move onto `i = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Because here in inner loop for the first iteration it would be

```
For j in range(1-1,0,-1):
```

Which equates to

```
For j in range(0,0,-1):
```

That range is an empty range so at i=1 inner loop won't run since condition evaluate to false